# Task 'testClasses' not found in project ':google-play-services-first-party'

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, testing, robolectric

I have an existing android project.

I want to add unit-tests using robolectric.

However, the project structure is weird and not standard.

1) How should I set the test path in gradle to be the custom one?

2) When I run the test via andorid-studio, I get this error:

```
Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'testClasses' not found in project ':google-play-services-first-party'.

* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

If I fix the project test structure, this should solve this as well?

I have tried to set in the gradle.build, the tests path:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            jni.srcDirs = []
//            jniLibs.srcDir 'libs'
        }
        test {
            java {
                srcDirs = ["test/com/waze/profile"]
                include "**/*Test.java"
            }
        }
```

[image]

my run configuration:

[image]

I cannot set a folder as a test source in the IDE:
I have tried "Project" perspective as well

[image]

In addition I cannot add a foler in the module root level. I allows only in inner leve:

[image]

Comment: Can you share your run configuration? It should not run tests for entire project but only for submodule

Comment: added a print-screen

Comment: And definition of the test sources is part only for java sub-project, correct?

Comment: how can I check this? I cannot set a folder as a "test source" in the AS like in intellij. I added a screenshot

Comment: it should be in `build.gradle` that java folder only

Comment: I have a build.gradle for the whole module. it appears in my qestion

Comment: You have many `build.gradle` files. It is visible from your screenshot

Comment: @EugenMartynov one `build.gradle` per module. So what's the problem with that?

Comment: I asked in one of the previous comment if definition of `testSource` is in `java` submodule on